# LaTeX Awesome CV - Space after entries

Tags: line-spacing, awesome-cv, vspace

[image]
[image]

for some sections, i do not wish to put a bullet/description, however a space is automatically generated regardless if the bullet or description is filled out. i want to make this space only generate if i am using a bullet point. photos above show the extra spacing i'm referring to. never used LaTeX before so this is foreign to me.

the code for the section i think should be altered, from the awesome-cv.cls file, is as follows:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
\vspace{-2.0mm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
\ifempty{#2#3}
  {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
  {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
  \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
\end{tabular*}%
}
```

full code as requested below:

```
% A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}

% Specify the location of the included fonts
\fontdir[fonts/]

% Color for highlights
% Awesome Colors: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange
%                 awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-darknight}
% Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color
% \definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8}

% Colors for text
% Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color
% \definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
% \definecolor{text}{HTML}{333333}
% \definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
% \definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{999999}

% Set false if you don't want to highlight section with awesome color
\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{false}

% If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else
\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sectioncolor}{\color}{\mdseries\color}{}{}
\makeatother

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Available options: circle|rectangle,edge/noedge,left/right
% \photo[rectangle,edge,right]{profile}
\name{}{}
% \position{{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}}
\address{}

\mobile{}
\email{}
\homepage{}
% \github{posquit0}
% \linkedin{posquit0}
% \gitlab{gitlab-id}
% \stackoverflow{SO-id}{SO-name}
% \twitter{@twit}
% \skype{skype-id}
% \reddit{reddit-id}
% \extrainfo{extra informations}

% \quote{``Be the change that you want to see in the world."}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

% Print the header with above personal informations
% Give optional argument to change alignment(C: center, L: left, R: right)
\makecvheader[C]

% Print the footer with 3 arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
% Leave any of these blank if they are not needed
%\makecvfooter
% {\today}
% {Claud D. Park~~~·~~~Résumé}
% {\thepage}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\input{resume/summary.tex}
\input{resume/education.tex}
\input{resume/experience.tex}
\input{resume/projects.tex}
\input{resume/skills.tex}
\input{resume/presentation.tex}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

the template is found here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm

code for education section:

```
\cvsection{Education}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cventries}

%---------------------------------------------------------
\cventry
{B.S. in Management Information Systems} % Degree
{Iowa State University} % Institution
{Ames, Iowa} % Location
{August 2014 - May 2018} % Date(s)
{}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}
```

Comment: Would you like to provide the *full* code (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) so we can even tune the header for you/

Comment: this seems to be the question asked earlier today, do you have two accounts? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464388/if-statement-to-remove-spacing-between-lines

Comment: ^was using a guest account at work, and couldnt log back in when i got home

Comment: You may want to add that AwesomeCV template is available at https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV, or at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm, to help other users locate the template.

Comment: Probably the fastest hack is to add `\vspace*{-8pt}` before the next `\cventry`.

Comment: ^ that worked for the space in the second photograph, but not in the first photograph- as there no \cventry following the single education @LianTzeLim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search into the `\cventry` definition was correct.  The issue you are having is basically that if the last argument of the `\cventry` command is empty, then you don't want the `\multicolumn{...}{...}{...}` to appear.  Therefore, you need to wrap an if-else statement around it.

Try changing the original:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}%
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

to:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else % THIS LINE ADDED TO CHECK IF LAST ARGUMENT IS EMPTY
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}% ONLY DO THIS IF #5 IS NOT EMPTY
    \fi % END OF THE IF STATEMENT
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

For illustration purposes, here is the default Awesome CV with the Education entry repeated twice (second time, contains an empty list):
[image: default Awesome CV showing empty list for \cventry]

And this image is the exact same document with the if-else statement shown above:
[image: added if-statement to remove empty space in Awesome CV showing empty list for \cventry]

EDIT:
If you have multiple `\cventry`s within a section and a middle `\cventry` has nothing for its final argument (i.e. the `% Description(s) of experience/contributions/knowledge` stuff), then put a space or `~` there.  Something like this: `\cventry{..1st arg..}{..2n arg..}{..3rd arg..}{..4th arg..}{}` becomes `\cventry{..1st arg..}{..2n arg..}{..3rd arg..}{..4th arg..}{ }`.  This will keep enough space between the two `\cventry`s.

NOTE:
There seems to be some type of hanging indent going one after the first entry (`\cventry`) in each section.  I didn't look carefully for where this is coming from.  I mention it here because you may notice the left-alignment is different for both entries under the section.  This is an unrelated issue.

Comment: could you post the code that you have for education.tex? i'm still getting the extra spacing but i think its because i am formatting education.tex incorrectly. thanks!

Comment: @jake Yeah, sorry, I accidentally had a space in the IF statement (i.e. `\if\relax\detokenize{#5} \relax\else`) but that space shouldn't be there.  I had it there while I was testing something.  The issue is that if you have an empty fifth argument for `\cventry` in the middle of other `\cventry`s, the space gets gobbled up too far.  A simple workaround for that is to use `{ }` as the last `\cventry` argument, instead of using `{}`.

Comment: I'll post the education code only if my previous comment (and edit) doesn't address your issue.  But, I literally just used the awesome cv template and copied the only education entry and pasted it again, plus deleted the last argument text.  Nothing special.

Comment: No problem.  I added an EDIT section to clarify this.  Hope it's clear enough!